# What is the alternative to position:sticky?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

As per the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position) on position property, `position: sticky` is still an experimental API. Also any version Internet explorer doesn't support it yet. So,

> Is there any way to achieve the same effect as that of `position: sticky` with or without javaScript?

I think that it is possible to acheive this effect with `position: fixed` and without javascript. Because the *In This Article* section on [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position) behaves exactly like position sticky was applied to it. Even when I disable javaScript it works well. The markup used by MDN I found with *inspect element* is as,

```
<div style="width: auto; max-height: none; top: 0px;" id="toc" class="toc toggleable">   ...  
</div>
```

When I scrolled down the mark up changed to include `fixed` class on the container `div`. I don't know how a new class is added without using javascript.

Comment: doesn't work for me with js disabled, are you sure you refreshed the page after disabling it ?

Comment: @Kaiido I didn't. You are right it doesn't work with js disabled. I think they used js which adds `fixed` class when the page is scrolled down to touch that `div`.

Answer (score 2):

use a javascript polyfill like fixed-sticky https://github.com/filamentgroup/fixed-sticky

on the *In This Article* section on MDN the `fixed` class is toggled via javascript, I do not think it's possible to toggle a class on a element on scroll event without resorting to javascript.